# ¿Cómo cargar los estilos de angular material con webpack 5?

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-material

Tengo angular 12 y Webpack 5.

Apenas estoy integrando webpack en la aplicación, al parecer ya carga las vistas, sin embargo, cargan sin estilos.

Este es mi código en webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const {TsconfigPathsPlugin} = require("tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin"); // used for paths in ts config
const {AngularWebpackPlugin} = require('@ngtools/webpack');
const CopyPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");

/* const root = path.join.bind(path, path.resolve(__dirname, '..'));
console.log(root('src', 'style.scss'));*/

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    polyfills: "./src/polyfills.ts",
    main: "./src/main.ts"
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.ts'],
    plugins: [
      new TsconfigPathsPlugin({})
    ]
  },
  devtool: "source-map",
  devServer: {
    port: 4200,
    historyApiFallback: true
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'), // output directory
    filename: "[name].js" // name of the generated bundle
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        /*loader: "ts-loader",*/
        use: [
          {
            loader: "ts-loader",
          },
          {
            loader: 'angular2-template-loader'
          } // to load component.html
        ],
        exclude: /\.(spec|e2e).ts$/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        loader: "html-loader",
        options: {
          esModule: false,
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|ico)$/i,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: ["to-string-loader", "css-loader"]
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          "to-string-loader",
          "css-loader",
          "sass-loader"
        ],
      },
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: "./src/index.html",
      favicon: './src/favicon.ico',
      inject: "body",
      scriptLoading: "blocking"
    }),
    new CopyPlugin({
      patterns: [
        {from: 'src/assets/i18n', to: 'assets/i18n'},
        /*{ from: 'src/assets', to: 'assets' }*/
      ]
    })
    /*,
    new AngularWebpackPlugin({
      tsconfig: './tsconfig.json',
    })*/ // to load component.html
  ]
};
```

Con la configuración normal de Angular solamente era agregar los estilos en angular.json

```
    "styles": [
      "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
      "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
      "src/styles.scss"
    ]
```

En la consola me sale este error `core.js:125 Could not find Angular Material core theme. Most Material components may not work as expected. For more info refer to the theming guide: https://material.angular.io/guide/theming`

Comment: ¿Porqué estas integrando webpack?

Answer (score 0):

Hola que tal te recomiendo utilizar un Schematic

> ng add @angular/material

para que el cli de angular se encargue de hacer las configuraciones, aqui mismo puede elegir el tema de su preferencia!